# From Parts DiagnosticError in Flutter while using ListView.Builder

Tags: flutter, listview

I have my widget as

```
Flexible(
   child: Column(
     children: [
       Expanded(
        child: SizedBox(
           width: double.infinity,
           height: double.infinity,
           child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: content.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return LocalChatItem(index: index);
            },
           ),
         ),
        ),
      ],
  ),
)
```

and I am getting below error -
throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
ErrorSummary('Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.'),
...parentDataWidget._debugDescribeIncorrectParentDataType(
parentData: renderObject.parentData,
parentDataCreator: _ancestorRenderObjectElement!.widget as RenderObjectWidget,
ownershipChain: ErrorDescription(debugGetCreatorChain(10)),
),
])

Please help we solving this error i am having headache now after looking for 1 month till now